# Computing time to login in a app

Tags: android, authentication

I want to compute login time my app takes it takes each time a user login in my app(android). Basically get this time as a report. what are the possible ways?

Comment: sorry dude, but absolutely unclear what you are asking. Please provide a relevant code of your project and explain exactly where you stuck.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs sorry to be abstract, new to android. I just want to know the time my app takes to login any user and show him his profile.Just to know how inefficient my current structure is.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please tell me which client you are using to Login like AysncHttp , Retrofit , OkHttp etc?
Because few client like Retrofit give you the execution time in response. But if you want to go with a manual way then you just have to follow these steps.

1. Get current time when you are calling the web-service, like this:

   ```
   long tStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
   ```
2. Get the current time again where you are getting the response, like this:

   ```
   long tEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
   ```
3. Calculate the time in seconds like this:

   ```
   long tDelta = tEnd - tStart;
   double elapsedSeconds = tDelta / 1000.0;
   ```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanx this helps. As i mentioned in the question can you suggest some way to generate this as report for each login time over a period (say one day).

Comment: The best way to achieve that is to mantain a local database (sqlite database). Every time the user is done with login you have to add an entry in database.

Comment: And also you have to use Alaram Manager to set an Alaram of 24 hours delay and when the alaram triggers, you have to set the alarm again for next 24 hours and push all the data of database to server.